# How to get results from a Mongoid query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am trying to get an array of results from a Mongoid query similar to the following SQL;

```
select field1, field2 from table;
```

The following returns a correct criteria, but I need the results

```
collection.only(:field1,:field2)
```

If I don't use the .only method, I can get results with .to_a:

```
collection.all.to_a
```

But if I add .to_a method along with the .only method:

```
collection.only(:field1,:field2).to_a
```

it returns an error "(Object doesn't support #inspect)"

This seems pretty basic, am I missing something?

Interesting note, this syntax works on the Mongodb console;

```
db.collection.find({ }, { field1: 1, field2: 1 })
```

but how to do this from Mongoid?

Comment: Have you tried `table.only(:field1,:field2).entries`

Comment: Yes, appears to behave the same as to_a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are looking for [`Criteria#pluck`](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#queries)

```
collection.pluck(:field1,:field2)
```

Comment: That works perfect!  I thought I scoured the documentation thoroughly, but I missed "Pluck" :-)